# Simulating Screen capturing as a webcam?

Tags: c#, .net, webcam, screen-capture

Do we have a way to simulate a webcam driver, that will provide realtime captured screen (30 frames per sec) as it's output?

Comment: You should add the KMDF tag to this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of several features of [ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com/) (free). It is a virtual webcam driver through which you can stream your real webcam video (with optional real-time video effects), video or image files, or your full/partial desktop.

Comment: It does do desktop to webcam for free.
It wasn't 'free' for many other tasks but it was well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just google video2webcam. It works quite well and will loop a video or picture as output.

Answer (score -2):

The driver's job is to provide a level of abstraction between the software and hardware.  The driver is supposed to issue commands to the hardware.  It's not responsible for taking pictures and turning it into an animated GIF for instance. It's going to do low level stuff like, turn the device on and off, send raw data to a socket.

That being said, if you need to create a virtual device driver.  Here's an overview of VDD's.  [Windows Programming/Device Driver Introduction](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Device_Driver_Introduction)

Generally these are not written in higher-level languages such as C#.  Rather, they are written in languages such as C/C++.  You will need the KMDF, or [Kernel-Mode Driver Framework.](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/wdf/KMDF.mspx)

If you just need to access a webcam from a .NET application on a system with a webcam, you just need an API.

Open your browser.. go to google.com and type ".NET webcam API"

You will see something like this:

[Webcam in your own application](http://weblogs.asp.net/nleghari/pages/webcam.aspx)

It appears that this is a wrapper for the DirectShow class.

Comment: The question is on simulating the webcam driver, not on capturing the webcam

Comment: updated my response... Thanks for the downvote.  The original question does not make it clear what he is trying to do.  I edited my response to handle a number of scenarios.

Comment: It appears you have completely missed the point of the question.